# Strange error when trying to npm start react file

Tags: react

I get that error while npm start

```
PS C:\Users\Concierge\downloads\prod\pdf2\ipfs_image_uploader> npm start

> react-box@0.1.0 start C:\Users\Concierge\downloads\prod\pdf2\ipfs_image_uploader
> node scripts/start.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'dotenv'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:580:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Concierge\downloads\prod\pdf2\ipfs_image_uploader\scripts\
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! react-box@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-box@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output ab
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Concierge\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-11-17T04_27_59_461Z-debug
PS C:\Users\Concierge\downloads\prod\pdf2\ipfs_image_uploader>
```

and when i run command npm install: I get that error:`> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /Users/user/Documents/pdfuploader/node_modules/scrypt

> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js
>
> scrypt@6.0.3 install /Users/user/Documents/pdfuploader/node_modules/scrypt
>   node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "/path/to/executable/python2.7", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:406:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:68:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/user/Documents/pdfuploader/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.2.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2018-11-18T05_45_00_864Z-debug.log`

Comment: Did you run `npm install` first?